How to fix "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000" 'error' event
node:events:495
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1817:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1865:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1953:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/parthsojitra/Desktop/Final_SMCar/Final_SMCar/Final_SMCar/SM_Car-API/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/parthsojitra/Desktop/Final_SMCar/Final_SMCar/Final_SMCar/SM_Car-API/index.js:50:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1844:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}

tell me what to do

Something else is running and using port 5000, likely your own code.  When in doubt, restart but really you need to see if your own code is still running.  Node seems to like to not stop when you expect.

"EADDRINUSE" stands for Error Address in use - it means that the address (host + port) you are trying to listen on is already in use.
To search which process is using a port on Linux you can use:
sudo ss -lptn 'sport = :5000'

for macOS (works on Linux as well):
sudo netstat -nlp | grep :5000

if you are on Windows - How do I find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?
